# get the values of specific location in any image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

if i have location of any points (in form of linear indexing  ) like

ind=34
    36
    56
    ......

now i want to get values of these locations in an image 'img'.
i-e value at location 34 in img,,value at location 36 in img and so on .
how to do??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get some portion from an image in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962346/how-to-get-some-portion-from-an-image-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

```
img(ind)
```

should do it for you.